# How to Remotely Debug a System Startup Component?

Tags: remote-debugging

Because of the possibility of full system failure, I am using VM's as the environment for debugging a system startup component like "userinit", which executes before the desktop appears. How do I configure the VM's remote debugger and system so I can debug from the first line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

[Setting Up Kernel-Mode Debugging Manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-kernel-mode-debugging-in-windbg--cdb--or-ntsd)